# W10 Computer can access shared folders on W7 through a wired connection, but not wireless

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

As stated in the title I'm trying to access files on a W7 computer from a W10 laptop. The network is setup to provide each of the computer's drives to appear as a shared folder within the root (//computer-name/). I have access to the root, but not any of the shared files within, when I'm connected through wifi, but it becomes full accessible when I'm plugged into ethernet.

1. Both computers are on the same subnet
2. Are on a private network (I've also attempted with them both on a public network)
3. In the same workgroup.
4. Share Permissions are set for everyone to have allowed Full Control, Change and Read.
5. I can ping both computers from one another in wired or wireless configurations.

Not sure what other information is relevant, but would be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have the wireless network recognized as public.

By default when you're connecting through a wired connection, the network will  be recognized as private by default and allows you to share files. When you connect through a wireless it'll ask you if that is a trusted network or not. If you select NO then it's a public network and files won't be shared

See [What’s the Difference Between Private and Public Networks in Windows?](https://www.howtogeek.com/245982/whats-the-difference-between-private-and-public-networks-in-windows/)

You need to [change the wireless to private](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/change-your-windows-7-network-location-public-home-or-work-2-steps) by opening Network and Sharing Center, click on the network and change it to private

You can also enable share files on public networks but it's not recommended

This is the default settings for private networks

[image: Private sharing]

And this is for a public network

[image: Public network sharing]

Comment: They are both set to be public networks, sorry for not mentioning this. I've tried setting them both to public and both to private and neither work.

Comment: then check there sharing settings. Also check if you can ping them from both wired and wireless connections

Comment: The share settings are simply set for "everyone" to be allowed full control, change and read. I can ping the computer whose files I wish to access from wireless or wired.